# Why is no sourcemap generated when minimizing source?

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, source-maps

I need to add source-maps to a Webpack 4 production build.

I am using the following config:

```
{
  …
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
  …
}
```

However, although this minimises the bundle, it results in a virtually empty source-map at `main.js.map`:

```
{"version":3,"file":"main.js","sources":["webpack://AdminFrontend/main.js"],"mappings":";AAAA","sourceRoot":""}
```

If i set `minimize` to `false`, I get a full source-map, but the bundle is enormous.

**What do I need to do to both minimize the source AND generate a full sourcemap?**

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you add source map for production build because as your application growth your source map is growing bigger which lead to your application performance is affected by the source map file

Comment: @Tony Ngo need source-maps for debugging production-only errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can customize webpack minimizer config like this

```js
const minify = (input, sourceMap, minimizerOptions, extractsComments) => {
  const { sourceMap: uglifySourceMap, code } = require('uglify-js').minify(input);
  return { map: sourceMap, code, warnings: [], errors: [], extractedComments: [] };
}
```

```js
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        parallel: true,
        minify: minify,
      }),
    ],
  },
```

after do that you will get full content map file